# Insert multiple value to marker.bindPopup in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a value in array like this

```
  [
   {
"officer_id": "T001",
"officer_name": "Michael",
"type_id": "1122",
"address": "12th Elm Street",
"address_description": "Chloe Toy Shop",
"description": "there's car accident in front of the shop",
"location": {
  "lat": -6.2613226,
  "lon": 106.7966812
}
]
```

And I have included that value into map marker. I want to ask how to insert two values in markers.bindPopup so when user click the icon, they can see two values, like description, address and officer who take responsibility.

I have insert 2 marker.bindPopup but it's not working. It's only one value that user can see when the icon has clicked.

Here's the script I have tried

```
    $.ajax({
    url: api_host+'reports',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
        {
            var latitude = response[i].location.lat;
            var longitude = response[i].location.lon;
            //console.log(latitude)
            var marker = L.marker([latitude,longitude]).addTo(map);

                marker.bindPopup(response[i].officer_name).openPopup();
                marker.bindPopup(response[i].description).openPopup();

        }
    }
})
```

Do you know how user can see more values when they click the icon?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at description if `bindPopup()` method in docs https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#layer (see section Popup methods), you will se that it takes as argument any HTML formated text.

In your case to show info in two lines, you could simply do something like this:

```
marker.bindPopup(response[i].officer_name + '</br>' + response[i].description).openPopup();
```